# How set a white color to the Form and in components simultaneously in runtime?

Tags: forms, delphi, colors

I'm need define a white color to my Form and in all others components, in runtime, where the final result, must be all area on screen ( ocuppied by Form ) also white, and after some time, the Form and the components can back like was before?

All components in my Form are:

- 01 **TImage** ( Aligned to *Client*, my Form in this case )
- 01 **TPanel** ( Centralized on Form )
- 01 **TImage** ( Aligned to *Client*, my Panel in this case )
- 01 **TGauge**

The layout must be something like this:

[image]

Then, how do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? What is the purpose?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, for not mix colors with a region that will be make with `CombineRgn` api.

Comment: The smell of an xy question only gets stronger. So, why don't you temporarily add a borderless form that covers the client area of your loading form? Or, covers the whole loading form (not only client area). Would that be useful?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, i understood your suggestion, but this way i will make a hole in two Forms :-(, i want make it only on loading form ( after of all stay white ). Is possible?

Comment: I don't want to guess what you are doing and what the problem is. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TomBrunberg, the question is: **Is possible make this form above ( and components ) totaly white?** yes or no?

Comment: All [this area](https://image.prntscr.com/image/xUEr7EDxSYGXHk1ZcW0Qaw.png) **white**, full form, including components.

Comment: Take a TRectangle, set it to align alClient and set the property Fill with a white color. Do right click-bring to front if needed. In this way you will get a totally white form (if this is what you want)

Comment: The answer is yes, it is possible.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, then what's your suggestion?

Comment: Use a white rectangle and set the visibility true/false

Comment: @AlbertoMiola, i'm using DX10 and not have this component `TRectangle`. Where i can find?

Comment: @Alberto and Jonas, `TRectangle` is a `FMX` object, so can't be used in a `Vcl` form.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, ok, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cover the client area with a borderless form of the same size, parented to your form, f.ex. in a method of your form

```
  cover:TForm;
...
  cover := TForm.Create(self);
  cover.Parent := self;
  cover.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  cover.Width := self.ClientWidth;
  cover.Height := self.ClientHeight;
  cover.Left := 0;
  cover.Top := 0;
  cover.Color := clWhite;
  cover.Visible := True;
```

To show your own form again, free the `cover` form or set `cover.Visible` to false.

Comment: I would use a `TFrame` instead of a second `TForm`.

Comment: Yes indeed @Remy. As my "defence" :), wording in the question says: *...the final result, must be all area on screen ( ocuppied by Form ) also white...*. From the start I deshiffered this to mean the whole form, including non-client area and therefore thought of using a form instead of any "client only" component. It was only in a later comment that Jonas indicated that he actually meant the client area only. I had already written an answer to cover the whole form, ready to be published, and so I only modified it to cover the client area only.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Just out of curiosity. Why should I/OP use a Frame instead of a Form? The only thing that comes to my mind is that you could add the Frame at design time.

Comment: @PhilippH. Frames are specifically designed to be embedded in other containers. Forms are not, even if they can be, they are not meant to be.